# Sticky element issue on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element which I wish to stick to the top of the page when scrolling down.  Functionally all of the code works thanks to another user on SO.  However when scrolling down on the phone it seems that the sticky element lags behind by a bit.  What I mean is the code seems to be calling every single time the parent element is scrolling and it causes hundreds or thousands of adjustments to the sticky element so it causes it to shake a bit.

Here is the code below:

HTML

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper">
  <div id="scroller-anchor"></div> 
  <div id="scroller" class="row visible-xs-block meal-controls">
     My sticky element is here and working   
  </div> 
</div>
```

JS

```
    $('#scroller-wrapper').scroll(function() {
      var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
      var $scroller = $('#scroller'); 
      var move = function() {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
        if(st > ot) { 
          $scroller.addClass('fixedElement');
        } else {
          $scroller.removeClass('fixedElement');
        }
    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move();
});
```

CSS

```
.fixedElement {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:10000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a possible and more effective solution would be to use `position: sticky` in CSS and not JS. You need to provide `top: 0` as well. Some compatibility is lagging in IE, but it is a viable solution already. Worth to check it [out here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

If you are worried about old browsers you may add a fallback function in JS, which still be somewhat laggy

Comment: this is what I'm doing in my app, but sticky support is still not quite there yet, so having a properly throttled JS fallback is still a good idea

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to `throttle` or `debounce` the call to update the element.

also why are you attaching a scroll listener to `window` inside of your wrapper scroll handler? that will mean that EVERY time that scroll listener is called, it will attach ANOTHER scroll listener to `window`.

all you need is the single handler on window, and allow propagation to do the rest.

```
// A debounce function wraps a function with a setTimeout,
// and then resets that timeout everytime it is called

function debounce(func, delay){
  var timeout, that = this;

  delay = delay || 300;

  return function() {
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      return func.apply(that, arguments)
    }, delay)
  }
}

// a throttle function ensures that a function isn't
// called more than once every interval

function throttle(fn, interval, shouldDebounce){
  var lastCall = 0, debouncedFn;

  interval = interval || 300

  if(shouldDebounce) debouncedFn = debounce(fn, interval);

  return function(){
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(now - lastCall < interval)
      return debouncedFn && debouncedFn.apply(this, arguments);

    lastCall = now;
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

// create a function to set scroll listeners
function setScroller() {
  var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor"),
      $scroller = $('#scroller'),
      onMove = function onMove() {
        var st = $(window).scrollTop(),
            ot = $anchor.offset().top;

        if(st > ot) { 
          $scroller.addClass('fixedElement');
        } else {
          $scroller.removeClass('fixedElement');
        }
      },
      // Throttle the onMove function to make sure it isn't called too often
      throttlededOnMove = throttle(onMove, 300);

  $(window).scroll(throttlededOnMove);
}

// attach scroll listener on document ready
$(setScroller)
```

Comment: what is the debounce function?

Comment: I added a sample function to the answer. debouncing means that if the function is called again before the last call timeout completed, it will clear the timeout and wait again

Comment: @chris updated my answer to throttle the number of calls instead of debounce them

Comment: for some reason this is not applying my css class as expected.  It does go into the necessary if statement section, but the css class never gets added and no error is thrown which is strange.

Comment: make sure the $scroller variable holds the correct element. Do you have other events that are adding and removing classes from that element? beyond that, a bug in jQuery is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @chris I also just found a typo in the throttle function